# Operator Merge - synchronization

Tags: java, rx-java2

I know that merge support concurrency. When I use two sources with different threads, is than performed synchronization (serialization)? Is emmiting items of different sources from merge operator blocking?

```
Observable.merge(
  firstDataSource()
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()),
  secondDataSource()
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
)
.filter(...)
.map(...)
.subscribe(...);
```

Is true that when first source emits data to merge tightly before second source than second souce must wait in merge operator until data of first source are passed to lambda oberver?

Comment: Data races are resolved in `merge` for you and your functions won't be called concurrently. The operator is non-blocking.

Comment: And what is result thread of merge operator and flatMap operator?

Comment: One of the participating threads. If you want to make sure the emission continues on a specific thread, use `observeOn` after `merge`/`flatMap`.

Comment: Will be emit thread of last item in queue or thread of first item?

Comment: It is random and there is no way to tell it which thread will it be in this situation.

Comment: And combineLatest is same case? Yes, i understand in case of combineLatest can be method drainAsync from multiple thread (is synchronized - AtomicLong and atomic queue).

Comment: It uses the so-called queue-drain serialization technique, there is always one thread at a time emitting events from these operators. Why are you interested in such internals?

Comment: It is for my better understanding of operators.